# AS2: Calculate the offset of MovieClip's new centre after removeMovieClip()

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, movieclip

I have a `MovieClip` containing MovieClips. The MovieClip's registration point is directly in the centre of it.

I then remove certain of the MovieClip's children, I want to calculate where the **real centre** point of this MovieClip is now but the registration point remains the same.

I can get the MovieClip's height and width however this is useless without knowing how far the MovieClip is offset from it's registration point now.

I have a diagram below which should help explain the situation better:

[image: diagram]

How would I calculate this offset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the `getBounds()` method:

```
var bounds = mc.getBounds(this); //Assuming this = mc._parent
var centerX = bounds.xMin + ((bounds.xMax - bounds.xMin) / 2);
var centerY = bounds.yMin + ((bounds.yMax - bounds.yMin) / 2);
```

Source: [getBounds API reference page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/help.html?content=00001274.html)

Comment: Thanks, your equations are off though. They should be: `var centerX = (bounds.xMin + ((bounds.xMax - bounds.xMin) / 2);` and `var centerY = (bounds.yMin + ((bounds.yMax - bounds.yMin) / 2);`

Comment: Sure, np, I've rectified the equations. Sorry about that :-)